# The argument 'path' must be a string or Uint8Array without null bytes. Received

Tags: reactjs, debugging, react-router, helper, programmers-notepad

ive been trying to run an old project of mine and i have this error massage in the console that says:

> The argument 'path' must be a string or Uint8Array without null bytes. Received

this is a react project .

anyone else bumped into a similar error massge?

would love to get help ,
thanks ahead.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

##### `Renaming your project folder fixes the problem.` If this does not work then move your project to other directory, it should fix the error.

Also please note that, the project should not contain the name of the framework. E.g,. project name  `react-app` throws error for react projects.

Similar issue: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/825